# Join two dataframes with inner join

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Say I have these two datasets:

```
Data frame 1:
X |  date
a |  1/1/2018
a |  1/2/2018
...
b |  1/1/2018
```

And df 2:

```
Holiday
1/1/2018
5/1/2018
```

What would be a elegant way to add a new column in the first dataset, with a 1 when the date has a match with second dataset?

Thank you very much!

Comment: create a column on df2 that only has 1 and merge df1 and df2 on date and holiday. A left join from df1 to df2 will provide the dates that are not in df2 as well. I am not sure if this elegant but it's practical :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This gets there with the `isin()` method.

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['1/1/2018', '1/2/2018', '1/1/2018']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Holiday': ['1/1/2018', '5/1/2018']})
df1
#        date
# 0  1/1/2018
# 1  1/2/2018
# 2  1/1/2018
df2
#     Holiday
# 0  1/1/2018
# 1  5/1/2018

df1['is_holiday'] = df1.date.isin(df2.Holiday).astype(int)

df1
#        date  is_holiday
# 0  1/1/2018           1
# 1  1/2/2018           0
# 2  1/1/2018           1
```

Answer (score 3):

The `isin` method of @Mike suffices for your answer, but just for your convenience, you can extend your dataframe with more information about the matches by using `merge` with an indicator:

```
df1.merge(df2, left_on='date', right_on='Holiday', how='left', indicator=True)

   X      date   Holiday     _merge
0  a  1/1/2018  1/1/2018       both
1  a  1/2/2018       NaN  left_only
2  b  1/1/2018  1/1/2018       both
```

Here we see our `_merge` column which indicates if the matches were in both or in left only.

Answer (score 1):

The words “merge” and “join” are used relatively interchangeably in Pandas and other languages, namely SQL and R. In Pandas, there are separate “merge” and “join” functions, both of which do similar things.

```
result = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = 'id_column')
result.head()
```

In your particular case, this is probably not totally necessary since you really want to conditionally add a column to an existing data frame. As @Mike suggested, you should use `isin()`. The only difference here is that I opted to use the `bool` data type instead of `int`.

```
df1['is_holiday'] = df1.date.isin(df2.Holiday).astype(bool)
```